# Removing duplicates from array using single loop

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, loops, duplicates

I want to remove duplicates from array using a single loop, it's not working, This is what I've done so far.

*Please note that I already know it works on sorted array, I use a single loop bubble sort for that, but I want it to work without sorting.*

**code.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define size 20
#define true 1
#define false 0

int main() {
    
    int input[size] = {1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2};

    int current = input[0], flag = false, index = 0;
    
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        if (current == input[x] && (flag == false)) {
            flag = true;
        } else if (current != input[x]) {
            input[index++] = current;
            current = input[x];
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    
    for (int foo = 0; foo < index; foo++) {
        printf("%d", input[foo]);
        printf((foo != index - 1) ? ", " : "");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**input**

```
1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2
```

**output**

```
1, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1
```

Comment: 0th: **sort the array** ... `qsort(input, size, sizeof *input, aminusb);`

Comment: The only way to remove duplicates with a single loop is with a hashset or equivalent.  Sorting the list first also works, but *technically* sorting involves many loops.

Comment: @pmg qsort use a loop for sorting

Comment: I haven't looked at the implementation of `qsort()`. For all I care it could have been written without a single loop, maybe using just recursion?? :-)

Comment: `calloc` a status bit array, check if previously found and mark off. If the next value exceeds the range, `realloc` and clear the new elements.

Comment: Also, sorting doesn't keep the original order of element appearences (in case it is a requirement)

Comment: There are ways to hack around and have just one _loop_ (ie. one keyword `for`), or even no loops (recursion). It's much more important to know which *time* you're aiming for: O(1), O(logn), O(n), O(n²)? etc... Because you may use recursion, one loop, gotos and what-not, but in the end, you will have a time boundary, which is what matters for sorting/removing duplicates/searching, etc...

Comment: And your desired output is ?

Comment: So not actually duplicates, but repetitions? That's easier, of course. First change: start `x` at one, not zero. Then, keep a reader and a writer index. Update both when not a duplicate, only reader if a duplicate.

Comment: Is your desired output a) `1, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2` or is it b) `1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2` ? That makes a big difference...

Comment: if your input domain is tractable you could use a bitfield to indicate the previous encounter elements... like a hashmap would be way overblown if you only need to track 0-9... you only need a short for that, and you get 6 extra bits to play with...

Comment: A more general solution: for all numbers in order, output and put it in a hash set only if the number doesn't exist in the hash set.

Answer (score 1):

There are several general solutions to this problem:

1. First sorting the array and then running your algorithm. This increases the complexity of the program to O(n log(n)) (general sorting algorithm) or O(n*w) ([radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), where w is a known constant depending on the size of the type in practice) at best and does not preserve the original order. In other words, this solution requires multiple loops.
2. Using a map to detect which elements have occurred already. A significantly more complex solution with an additional O(log n) complexity.
3. If the range of possible elements is small, e.g. constrained to only the numbers 0 to 9, you could use a boolean array to keep track of which values occurred. This is essentially a simple version of the "map solution". This is the only option requiring a single loop.
   Code example:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 20

int main()
{
    int input[ARRAY_SIZE] = {1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2};
    bool hasOccurred[10] = {0}; // The indices are used as keys

    size_t newSize = 0U;
    for (size_t arrayIdx = 0U; arrayIdx < ARRAY_SIZE; ++arrayIdx)
    {
        if (!hasOccurred[input[arrayIdx]])
        {
            hasOccurred[input[arrayIdx]] = true;
            input[newSize++] = input[arrayIdx];
        }
    }

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < newSize; ++idx)
        printf("%d%s", input[idx], idx != newSize - 1U ? ", " : "\n");
}
```

Output:

```
1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2
```

4. Use a combination of the previous algorithm and counting sort. First, initialize a `int hasOccurred[10]` array with `-1` values. Then loop over the `input` array and, for each "new" element, store the `input` array index in the has occurred array. This array can be used as a sorted array (iterate ignoring the `-1` values) or it can be used to construct an output array in which the original order is preserved. Depending on the use-case, this requires more than one loop.

[AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx) adds that variations on a boolean array are possible, such as using the individual bits of an `unsigned int` to store the "has occurred" flags. This is a speed/memory tradeoff.

Credit to [pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25324/pmg) for suggesting radix sort.

Comment: For very small ranges of possible elements, you can even use a single integer as a bitmap.

Comment: @AKX Nice addition, thank you. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: I don't understand this version of c, and also i'd like to avoid a second array

Comment: @Arghadip I'm sorry, I didn't mean to write unintelligible C. What is it exactly that is unclear?

Comment: You can [Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) in `O(n)`... just saying

Comment: @pmg Good point! It's still O(w*n), where w is the key length, isn't it? I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @Arghadip Solving this in one loop is not possible without using another data structure. If the program is evaluating a number in the middle of the array it needs to somehow "know" whether that element has occurred or not. Either by keeping a list of occurred elements, or by iterating over the array again.

Comment: @Yun, yes `O(w*n)`, but you can make `w` be `1`... 1 char for values `0` to `255`, 1 short for values `0` to `65535`, ...

Comment: @pmg Okay, true, `w` is fixed if the size of the type is known, which it is in practice. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution that uses [qsort()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) to sort the input array, before removing the duplicate elements, as already suggested in the comments above:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 20

static int _compare(const void * a, const void * b) {
    return ( *(int *)a - *(int *)b );
}

int main(void)
{
    int data[ARRAY_SIZE] = {1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2};
    int index = 1;
    
    qsort(data, ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(data[0]), _compare);
    
    for (int i = 1; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        if (data[i-1] != data[i]) {
            data[index++] = data[i];
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        printf("%d ", data[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Console output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: My previous answer was not correct and didn’t answer that actual question. Thanks @Yun for pointing out that it contained a solution with two loops. The other example I’ve post also didn’t work correctly, so I’ve deleted it to not clutter Stack Overflow with wrong answers, sorry for that.